# java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am making a quartz thread application that is collect data from a table and insert it in another table after inserting it is updating the data base
but when i got the above error i got some of the data inserted twice in the table

**Note that :**
1.**I use Oracle DB**
2.****OJDBC6.jar** to connect**
3.all tables are in same schema

StackTrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed. 
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDriver.java:263) 
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDriver.java:268) 
        at com.sender.gsm.dao.Dao.closeConnection(Dao.java:38) 
        at com.sender.gsm.dao.OutDataDao.insertData(OutDataDao.java:91) 
        at com.sender.gsm.jobs.DataHandler.execute(DataHandler.java:49) 
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) 
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

The close connection function is

```
public void closeConnection(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        if (conn != null ) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Somewhere else the connection is already closed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> at com.sender.gsm.dao.Dao.closeConnection(Dao.java:38) 
>   at com.sender.gsm.dao.OutDataDao.insertData(OutDataDao.java:91)

From the stack traces ,you are closing the connection while performing the insert after select. try creating the new connection.

You might have called for `closeConnection()` method after select statement.So an exception is thrown at runtime when it tried to execute the query the connection is closed.

If you are using **connection pooling** , make sure have configured the `maxIdle` and `maxActive` parameters to the reasonable values